# keras multi output softmax model input shape

Tags: keras, neural-network, output

I have the following model:

```
from keras.layers import Activation, Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate, concatenate

input_ = Input(batch_shape=(512, 36))

x = input_
x1 = Dense(4)(x)
x2 = Dense(4)(x)
x3 = Dense(4)(x)
x4 = Dense(4)(x)

model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=[x1, x2, x3, x4])
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',  metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, test, epochs=20, batch_size=512, verbose=2, shuffle=False, validation_data=[X, test])
```

My Y has the following format:

```
 col1 col2 ... col 4
  1    0         2
  0    0         2
  2    1         1
```

and is reshaped via:

```
y = to_categorical(Y).reshape(4, -1, 3)
```

However, when running the fit command, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that 
you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected 
to see 4 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: 
[array([[[1., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0.],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Y is a numpy matrix?
Try this:

```
y = [to_categorical(Y[:, col_numb]).reshape(-1, 3) for col_numb in range(Y.shape[1])]
```